# Why are constants considered as mutable in Javascript, when only partially true?

Tags: typescript, pointers, enums, constants, immutability

In Javascript, as specified by the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const):

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It
>   does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable
>   identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the
>   content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its
>   properties) can be altered

However, trying to alter a string, or number, will error out as `TypeError: invalid assignment to const`. If that is the case, why isn't a const considered as mutable in any scenario where a const is a value other than an array, or object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great question and gives opportunity to clarify some of the greater nuances of Javascript as a language.

#### Understanding Pointers

In certain programming languages, there is a concept as a pointer. A pointer is a variable containing the address of another pointer. Therefore in a language like c, a const being read-only and mutable is more apparent:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    const int counter = 0;
    *(int *)&counter = 39;
    printf("%d", counter);
}
```

In the above C code, we create a readonly reference to 0. However, by using pointers, we cast a value pointing to counter, and then point to that value once again. Counter will not consider it as altering value directly. So we see that in a language using pointers, such a code is possible to do.

However, the question then becomes, what about Javascript where there is no concept as a pointer? Maybe a const in a situation other than an Object, or Array should be considered as immutable.

#### Javascript as a Prototypical Language

This then goes onto the next point. Javascript is a prototypical language. This means, that everything in Javascript is ultimately represented by objects building off of each other. Which this knowledge in mind, all we have to do is crawl to highest object available AKA document, or window.

#### Using our knowledge of Pointers and Prototypes

Therefore it would stand, that even a read-only value such a const in Javascript should theoretically have some sort of way of being mutated. So the question is, how could one go ahead and do that?

#### Code Example - Mutating a Const

```
const test = 'foo';
window['test'] = 'value mutated';
console.log(test);
// value emitted 'value mutated'
```

In the above code example, the value that will be consoled out, will be `value mutated`. This is because in any browser setting, the window + document object will cache all variables. This allows values to be mutated, because compiler will not register as readonly value being mutated. We are creating a pointer(so to speak) on value using window, which creates another reference point. So yes, a const is mutable for values other than strings, or numbers, even though it is a read-only value!

#### Code Example - (Attempting) to Mutate an Enum

Attempt to mutate an immutable enum in Typescript

```
enum testTwo {
  test = 'value immutable'
}
const pointerToTestTwo = 'testTwo.test';

window[testTwo.test] = 'value mutated';
console.log(testTwo.test);
// value emitted 'value immutable'
```

will not work. This is because an enum in typescript is compiled as a IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), with no reference point. The only way to change enum would be to create another function which references enum.

So yes, to end this point off. A read-only const is indeed mutable in Javascript in all scenarios as opposed to an enum in Typescript, which is immutable. Feel free to take a look at my article which discusses this a bit more: [Enums V. Constants](https://medium.com/razroo/typescript-enums-v-constants-576536163cc9)

Answer (score 2):

> However, trying to alter a string, or number, will error out as `TypeError: invalid assignment to const`

That's precisely what documentation says — *variable identifier cannot be reassigned*.

A `const` identifier will always point at the same place. However, the contents of this place might change.

If that place is an object, there are a number of ways to mutate it (`Object.prototype.assign`, the `delete` keyword, property assignment). For primitive types, there is just no way to dereference (“grab”) the contents other than by changing their identifiers (which is not allowed for `const`). That's why constant primitives are immutable and constant objects are not.